# Installing XLConnect in Studio

Tags: xlconnect

Trying to install XLConnect. Material seems to have downloaded, but not quite sure of next step or where to look.

```
> install.packages('XLConnect')
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.3/XLConnect_0.2-12.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5546911 bytes (5.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.3 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/n9/v_01bfk905s6hp0nqkb7td6r0000gn/T//RtmpLX6VE6/downloaded_packages
>
```

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to "load" the package with: library("XLConnect"). Also check out the documentation in CRAN for commands to use the package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/XLConnect.pdf.

Let me know if this helped